# emma code coverage report

Tags: report, code-coverage, emma

I have a maven project which follows common core web package.

I want to run Emma tool for code coverage. The requirement is I want to run emma code coverage tool to my maven based project and generate a report.

I am completely new to this tool and trying out the commands as specified in internet. As I don't have any main method in my maven project(we get the ear and deploy in jboss), I had to create a pojo file to invoke a service and build the pojo jar by including the maven project jars.

Now I have only emma.jar in my system, a jar containing the main method and the maven project jars. As I want in report based format from the tool, I run the emma tool from batch command(in the location where emma.jar is present) -> `java emmarun -jar <jar containing the main method>`

I get the report as

```
[EMMA v2.0.5312 report, generated Thu Mar 29 20:36:04 IST 2012]
OVERALL COVERAGE SUMMARY:

[class, %]  [method, %] [block, %]  [line, %]   [name] 
100% (5/5)  79%  (11/14)    77%  (266/344)! 76%  (60/79)!   all classes

OVERALL STATS SUMMARY:

total packages: 1 total classes:    5 total methods:    14 total executable files:  4 total executable lines:   79

COVERAGE BREAKDOWN BY PACKAGE:

[class, %]    [method, %]      [block, %]      [line, %]    [name] 100% (5/5)
79%  (11/14)  77%  (266/344)!  76%  (60/79)!   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But from here I don't understand which are the class files that are covered during method invocation from the pojo file bundled in the jar.

I am not sure about my approach or is there any other step I am missing to get the report?

---

is there any ref links to unit tests..how can I code a simple unit test...the usage steps was quite confusing.So I thot of any simple step to test the maven project using command prompt for code coverage...else is there any other tool other then emma which can simplify my approach...I want to use some code coverage tool to test a maven project from command prompt..this is my main requirement

Comment: please tell us, how exactly you created the report. Otherwise it will only be guessing.

Comment: Requirement is I want to run emma code coverage tool to my maven based project(containing common core web package) and generate a report.As I dont have any main method in my maven project(we get the ear and deploy in jboss), I had to create a pojo file to invoke a service and build the pojo jar by including the maven project jars.Now I have only emma.jar,a jar containing the main method and the maven project jars.As I want in report based format from the tool,I run the emma tool from batch command(in the location where emma.jar is present)->java emmarun -jar <jar containing the main method>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [QuickStartGuide](http://emma.sourceforge.net/intro.html).

You have to provide the source code and create an html report, to view complete statistics.

Example:

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun -r html -jar the_jar -sp path_to_source
```

Comment: here what does the_jar refers to and path_to_source refers to?

Comment: @bablu to the jar file and the path to your source files , it is like your own example, only with html report and -sp paramater for the sources

Comment: here what does the_jar refers to and path_to_source refers to? I have a maven project containing common core web package structure. As I dont have any main method, do I need to write a pojo as done earlier and call any ejb service method to test for code coverage? I am not clear of the understanding of this tool and code coverage process. Can you please highlight the steps in need to perform assuming I have only maven project(containing common core web package without main class) and emma jar?

Comment: while running the command apart from generating the report, I am also getting some exception in the command prompt-
emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Test] does not have a runnable public main() method..But the pojo file Test.java contains main method where ejb method of the maven's project is called

Comment: @bablu you confuse me, you stated in your question that you already executed emma by using the command line. So you already have something working. All I did was to point out, how you get a better coverage report. Frankly, I don't understand what your problem is right now. You definitely need a main method in your jar, to execute whatever ever you want to execute and measure.

Comment: Yes I have a main method..I was just asking the steps to be followed from the scratch assuming I have only maven project...ok thats not an issue..the report is getting created but with an exception..the main method file that I created is just calling the ejb method.Then I am exporting it as jar which extracts the common and core jar from the maven project and I get a single jar containing main method class file and maven project jar which I give input in the command prompt.

Comment: I think I am complete wrong in my approach which confused you. Just think I have a maven J2EE project and that project does not have a main method. Now how can I perform code coverage by emma? As you stated main method is required, should I create a simple Java project containing one class with main method and invoke any ejb method in my main J2EE project to test for code coverage?

Comment: @bablu you should write unit tests and use the [emma maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/emma-maven-plugin/). That would be the standard way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As you use Maven anyway you should also use it to generate the Emma reports:

```
mvn emma:emma
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-jar`, `-cp` may help.

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun -cp Test.jar MainClassName
```